# When I try to modify this record, why do I get an error that says it's a lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

Here's the code that I'm working with, where I create records and then try to modify them:

```
(defrecord Record [Name Age Index ClassIndex])

(defn read-csv [fname count]
  (with-open [file (io/reader fname)]
    (doall (map #(str/split % #",") ;; doesn't work with commas in text fields
             (take count (line-seq file))))))

(defn make-record [idxs types row]
  (apply ->Record
    (map (fn [idx t]
           (let [value (nth row idx)]
             (case t
               :string value
               :int (Integer/parseInt value)
               :long (Long/parseLong value))))
             idxs types)))

(def records
  (doall (map (partial make-record
                [0 1 2 3]
                [:string :int :long :int])
           (read-csv "C:/Users/user/Documents/URECA/hi/lib/test.csv" 1))))

(reset! records
  (map #(assoc % :ClassIndex
         (+ (:Age %) (:Index %)) :Age (+ 1 :Age %))
    @records))
```

When I run this code, I get this exception:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to
clojure.lang.IDeref  clojure.core/deref (core.clj:2080)
```

Why am I getting this error?

**Updated in response to comment:**

I have a map of records and I want to update those records. The class `:Index` would be determined by the value of `:Age` + `:Index`. However, the initial values of `:Age` and `:Index` would be read in from a file.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `reset!` is for atoms, and you are trying to apply it to a sequence. By the way, `doall` doesn't change the fact that your sequence is lazy, it simply forces it to be evaluated and reside in memory.

Comment: You're trying to change an immutable data structure. Read this: http://clojure.org/functional_programming#Functional%20Programming--Immutable%20Data%20Structures

Comment: Is there anyway i could change the data structure by calling a new instance of it. As far as i know. I could define a new data structure with the same parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "[Can I create mutable state inside Clojure records?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554178/244494)" is closely related to yours. The critical points are

1. Records usually immutable.
2. [The `reset!` function operates on atoms](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reset!).

You're getting that exception because `reset!` is figuring out that you've given it a parameter that it can't handle and because what you gave it is immutable. The best way to fix the underlying problem is to figure out if you need a record or a mutable data structure, and to change your representation of the data appropriately. If you do continue to use a record (i.e. this is going to be immutable and you only have to care about setting values on a record once) you could move the changes to `:Index` and `:Age` into the `make-record` function. However, you're probably better off using references to an immutable data structure and changing the references on updates.