# How to remove element from mutable vector?

Tags: vector, clojure, mutable

I know how to create mutable vector:

```
(defn create-vector []
  (intern *ns* (symbol "my-vector" (ref []))
=>my-namespace/my-vector
```

I know how to add element to that vector:

```
(dosync (alter my-vector conj "test"))
=>["test"]
```

Now I have `"test"` string in my mutable vector. But how I can remove it? I tried to use lazy-sequence function `remove`

```
(dosync (alter my-vector remove "test"))
```

but it doesn't work. How can I remove element from mutable vector?

EDIT:
The collection doesn't really have to be vector. I found solution for set, but will wait if someone will suggest solution for vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mistake is that you pass the `"test"` arg to `remove` function, while it really accepts a predicate. In your case this one wold work (unproperly though, making a list instead of a vector):

```
(dosync (alter my-vector #(remove #{"test"} %)))
```

to keep it a vector you would have to do this:

```
(dosync (alter my-vector #(vec (remove #{"test"} %))))
```

what makes me curious about your example:

1. why would you use this weird construction:

   ```
   (defn create-vector []
     (intern *ns* (symbol "my-vector" (ref []))))
   ```

   instead of just `(def my-vector (ref []))`
2. why do you use `ref` at all? would you be using it inside some transaction? if not, i would propose you to move to an `atom` (since it is also thread safe)

   ```
   user> (def my-atom (atom []))
   #'user/my-atom

   user> (swap! my-atom conj "hello")
   ["hello"]

   user> (swap! my-atom #(remove #{"hello"} %))
   ()
   ```

Comment: Can you just confirm my understanding? With that construct we actually don''t modify collection, but instead change reference `@my-vector` to point into new created mutable vector. Am I right?

Comment: in fact, there are no mutable vectors, but mutable *references*. Your vectors always stay immutable, while reference points to a newly constructed one (clojure's data model makes it quite a cheap operation)

Comment: well, in fact there are mutable structures, transients for example, (http://clojure.org/reference/transients) but it is rather more advanced optimization point, so approach with caution

Comment: So I got it right. To answer your question why I use such a construct. Well this is what I could find in internet. I'm Clojure beginner who try to create "mutable" collection, without actually studying how to do it. Construction from question was actually found on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5554870/5026241. Atoms are the next chapter in the book I follow, but I need to complete my assignment into Friday :).

Comment: then i would probably advise you to spend a couple of hours reading some proper introduction to the language, this would be much more efficient, then reading some random posts on SO ) http://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/

Comment: I follow the book "Living Clojure" which I find better for me than "Clojure for Brave and True". As I stated the next chapter is about concurrency where atoms are described (atom definition in Clojure differs from Lisp atom). Will read it for sure, but for now I need to complete my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in my edit, collection doesn't have to be really vector. @leetwinski posted answer how to do it for vector, but if I would decide to use set I found other solution. So if we create set the same way as in question replacing `[]` to `#{}`:

```
(defn create-vector []
  (intern *ns* (symbol "my-set" (ref #{}))
=>my-namespace/my-vector
```

and add element:

```
(dosync (alter my-set conj "test"))
=>#{"test"}
```

, we can remove it

```
(dosync (alter my-set disj item))
=>#{}
```

Comment: i think you've meant `disj` in the last line. `(dosync (alter my-set disj "test"))`